# Remove array based on index from other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove array `arr` based on index from other array `arr2`. `arr2` can have any length.

**Expected Output**

```
["test9495","test93992"]
```

```js
var arr = ["test234", "test9495", "test234", "test93992", "test234"];    

var arr2 = [0, 2, 4];

console.log(arr.splice(arr2,arr2.length))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: What's your desired output? You haven't told us what you aim out of this. You've told, what you want.

Comment: Desired output is at the top (Expected Output).

Comment: Could you explain the correlation between `arr` and `arr2` further? I don't understand how `[0, 2, 4]` should result in `["test9495","test93992"]` getting picked...

Comment: Are the indexes in arr2 always going to be present in arr? Or it can be out of bounds too?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma [0, 2, 4] are indexes (positions) of arr which I want to remove

Comment: @Perry  Yes the indexes in arr2 always going to be present in arr

Comment: use filter function and check whether each index matches with item

Answer (score 4):

```
const arr = ["test234", "test9495", "test234", "test93992", "test234"];
const arr2 = [0, 2, 4];
const arr3 = arr.filter((item, index) => arr2.indexOf(index) === -1);
console.log(arr3);
```